# ELisp regexp: match group if followed by other regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am writing a major Emacs mode for a basic language I am implementing. I am wanting to highlight syntax for method calls where the method name is checked by `[a-z][^()]*` but only when followed by `([^)])`. How would I define a regular expression which would match the first part if followed by the second part, but not highlight the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'my-mode
  '(("\\(\\b[a-z][^()]*\\)([^)]*)"
  1 font-lock-function-name-face t)))
```

The 1 says to apply the highlight to the first subexpression.

Note: I added a `\\b` to make it match only when the `[a-z]` begins a word (otherwise `Dude()` would have the `ude` highlighted), and I added a `*` in the last set of parens b/c it seemed like it was missing.

I tested this in c++-mode.

Documentation for font-lock-add-keywords and other font lock things can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html).